# how to use local flutter package in another flutter application?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to use local flutter package in another flutter application?

I created a package using following command:

```
flutter create --template=package my_new_package
```

and then in my application source code => main.dart

```
import "package:my_new_package/my_new_package.dart" // can not find the package
```

Comment: I have the same trouble. Though the app ran, the error, “The URI doesn’t exists” occurred. I executed “flutter packages get”, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Find this file in your flutter application => pubspec.yaml

Use local dependency

```yaml
    dependencies:
       flutter:
         sdk: flutter
       my_new_package:
         path: ./my_new_package
```

Note: The `./my_new_package` above means that the `my_new_package` directory containing the `pubspec.yaml` for the package is a sub-directory of the app.

If you have the package as a directory at the same level as the app, in other words one level higher up in the directory tree, you can use `../my_new_package` (note the double dot) or a full path to the package directory.

Comment: **Caution:** There is a trap here that I would like to caution people against. Do not create a folder in your flutter root named `packages` and put packages in there. `packages` folder is removed on build.

Comment: @TheGwa Where do you see the author of this answer using a packages directory? I would assume you'd just have your package at the same level as your test project, not a package inside a test project.

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper the above answer is correct and without fault. My comment is just a caution. If you have project specific packages, the naive approach would be to put them in a `/packages` directory at the root of your project at the same level as `/android`,  `/ios`,  `/tests` etc. At the time of writing `/packages` was overwritten during build and would nuke your packages. Have not tested for some time.

Comment: The official documentation link is [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages), for package and plugin.

Comment: Hello. I can't seem to find anywhere how to publish package only locally without publishing it to pub.dev or pub.dartlang...

Comment: @TheGwa Oh. That is useful info. Thanks. Maybe call it something like `plugins` or add them to `lib/packages`? Perhaps the community should come up with a convention.

Comment: It does seem that the `/packages` is no longer overwritten during build and the official documentation mentions no limitation of putting files in a directory named that way. I believe the warning no longer applies.

Answer (score 41):

Path dependency: A Flutter app can depend on a plugin via a file system path: dependency. The path can be either relative or absolute. For example, to depend on a plugin plugin1 located in a directory next to the app, use the following syntax:

```
dependencies:
  plugin1:
    path: ../your_package/
```

Comment: This was useful for me when i wanted to depend a plugin to a plugin in the same path.

Comment: To highlight again, your app and the package should be in same directory

Answer (score 19):

For the full process:

1. Download the code for the plugin you want to use and place it at the "same" level as your flutter project directory

   ```
    -- plugin-name  
    -- your flutter directory -- lib
                              -- android
                              -- ios etc etc
   ```
2. Add the plugin path to pubspec.yaml. *If you are unsure of the correct plugin name to use, look at the `name:` attribute in the plugin's pubspec.yaml file. The plugin directory must also be saved with the same `name:`

   ```
   dependencies:
    plugin-name:
      path: ../plugin-name
   ```
3. Run `Pub get` and you can import just like any other plugin. Only difference is when you click on any of the plugin classes during development, it will point to the local file.

*Note: Also delete the "example" folder that comes with the package. You don't need it and it will be a pain to maintain during project upgrades.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I had same problem once I started using flutter.
I have implemented example of `pdf_view` plugin in my app for making changes for Shimmer effect instead of `CircularProgressIndicator()`.

**Some Knowledge**

> You can edit plugins which are get by  `flutter pub get` but they might be replaced when you create app bundle by flutter.

Now your answer with sample plugin suppose take an example of `advance_pdf_viewer`
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer)

1. Download zip file and extract it in `pdf_viewer/`
2. Make sure `pdf_viewer/` has all files including `lib`, `Android`, `iOS` and all related files.
3. Copy your `pdf_viewer` folder in your project directory for example
   my project is `invoice_viewer` so it's root directory have all folders such as `lib`, Android, `iOS` etc. copy it in this root directory along with `lib`, `Android`, `iOS`.
4. Now open your `pubsec.yaml` and write code as follows

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #  advance_pdf_viewer: ^2.0.0
  advance_pdf_viewer:
    path: ./pdf_viewer
```

5. In comment I have replaced server version with local one and make changes in plugin's `viewer.dart` file to achieve desired changes.

Hope you and other got some information from this finding!