# How to call class or functions in another packages to another packages in flutter?

Tags: flutter, package, call

I have a structure project like this:

[image: structure project]

I tried to implement `modularization` on flutter like the one on Android native (Java and Kotlin) where it functions to `separate` between `functions` and speed up the build process and simplify future `maintenance`.

In the image, there is a `root project` with the name "`cari_mobile_flutter_main`" and 2 flutter packages with the name "`cari_news`" and "`cari_network`". I managed to connect the `2 packages` with the `root project` by `setting` the `path` to `pubspec.yaml` in the `root project`. So that the `lib` folder in the root can `access/call` `class` and `functions` from `both packages`.

The problem is `how can each package be connected so that they can call each other's class or function?` For example: "`cari_news`" can call `class` or `functions` that are in "`cari_network`". Can it do that?

Because I have tried to set up the `path` on `pubspec.yaml` between the package and it can't and there is an error like this:

[image: this is pubspec.yml from cari_news]

I already try to click "packages get" in the top right and get the result like this:

> Running "flutter packages get" in cari_news...
>   Because cari_news depends on cari_network from path which doesn't
>   exist (could not find package cari_network at "cari_network"), version
>   solving failed. pub get failed (66) Process finished with exit code 66

I tried linking `cari_network` with `cari_news` so that the `cari_news` package can call `class` and `functions` that are in the `cari_network` package. But that can't be. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There's already a similar thread. Try the solution if it works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238420/how-to-use-local-flutter-package-in-another-flutter-application

Comment: I already try it, but still not work if set the path in the package like the picture above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, for the answer to my question, I just add `../cari_network` to the `path` section. Because the position of the `cari_network` package is inside the `root` project while `cari_news` is in the `root` project and the `pubspec.yaml` is in the `cari_news` package. So to find the `cari_network` package just add a `../` only.