# How to use a flutter plugin locally?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

Let's say we have created a plugin with flutter. Named **flutter_local_plugin**.
How can we put it inside a flutter project **flutter_some_application** and access it?
There is a question here ([how to use local flutter package in another flutter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238420/how-to-use-local-flutter-package-in-another-flutter-application)), but the accepted answer has 0 explanations regarding the actual file migrations.

- we only need the plugin to be placed inside the **flutter_some_application**, without any **example** from the package project.
- Where do you place the .kt & .dart files, and how do you link all of this together?

There seems to be no guide on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a flutter plugin by Android Studio 4.0 which name is printer.
We can get a tip at the pubspec.yaml:

```
  printer:
    # When depending on this package from a real application you should use:
    #   printer: ^x.y.z
    # See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints
    # The example app is bundled with the plugin so we use a path dependency on
    # the parent directory to use the current plugin's version. 
    path: ../
```

Then I use printer locally in another flutter project:

```
  printer:
    path: ../printer/
```

After pub get I found printer added in .flutter-plugins & .flutter-plugins-dependencies automatically.

Comment: this answer doesn't really make sense without an explanation. I made a plugin but the ../ path doesn't work.