# Flutter Pinput Overflowed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using an imported PinPut Flutter package and I am trying to fix the overflowed pinput on the right. I have tried setting the eachFieldWidth and eachFieldHeight to the smallest value but it doesn't make any difference.

```
return PinPut(
  fieldsCount: 6,
  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
  eachFieldWidth: 40.0,
  eachFieldHeight: 40.0,
  focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
  controller: _pinPutController,
  submittedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
  selectedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
  followingFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
  pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.fade,}
```

[PinputOverflowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQYhT.png)

Comment: Try wrapping it in an Expanded widget

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work

Comment: you can try this code
```.
eachFieldWidth:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/5.9
```

Comment: I have tried the responsive width, it's still the same

Comment: UPDATE on post: The pinput field is no longer overflowed by setting the minimum height and width in a box constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'pull requests' that is waiting to merge.
If you want to adapt to that modification, you need to change Pinput package.
Or you need to wait for merging that commit.
https://github.com/Tkko/Flutter_PinPut/pull/37/commits/7b1c49bda70455aac6ddecc6ab991d1662835de4

-Before adapt that commit

[image]

-After adapt that commit

[image]

If you changed from Pubdev package to local package,
please look for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238420/how-to-use-local-flutter-package-in-another-flutter-application).