# Add one flutter app to another existing flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-module

Is there any way to merge a smaller flutter app to another flutter app?
I'm finding ways to merge the flutter app to a native android app, but can we do it to another flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

It call `package` in VsCode: **View > Command palette > Flutter: New project**, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238420/how-to-use-local-flutter-package-in-another-flutter-application) is how to implement it to your project.

[image]

Comment: But will this just be like a fix for running locally?
Because I need it running on a website with the parent app