# How to solve the error on outdated code when cloning

Tags: flutter, dart, github, clone, dart-pub

I am recently want to see and run some other developers code in github and clone it to run in my emulator but it showing some error like this

"Running "flutter pub get" in budgex...
Because budgex depends on basic_utils from path which doesn't exist (could not find package basic_utils at "..\packages\basic-utils-3.3.3"), version solving failed.
pub get failed (66; Because budgex depends on basic_utils from path which doesn't exist (could not find package basic_utils at "..\packages\basic-utils-3.3.3"), version solving failed.)"

i am was trying to install basic_utils package but seem failed how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link to get packages in the given environment like VS code, or save your code while pubspec.yaml file is opened – it will get flutter packages for you automatically.

Comment: thanks for answering the question, by the way how to click link? can you tell me how thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are trying to use a library on your local computer: `basic_utils`; the pub command is searching it in the path `..\packages\basic-utils-3.3.3` but it can't find the library there.

In the `pubspec.yaml` you should have something like this:

```
  basic_utils:
    path: ..\packages\basic-utils-3.3.3
```

You should be ok replacing this with:

```
  basic_utils: 3.3.3
```

If the developer has made changes to the library you should ask him the changed library and then update the `pubspec` with the correct location like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238420/how-to-use-local-flutter-package-in-another-flutter-application).

Comment: i am done changing some basic utils but now getting problem in flutter_html like this one "Because flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 depends on html >=0.15.0 <1.0.0 and every version of link_previewer depends on html ^0.14.0+2, flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 is incompatible with link_previewer."