# is it possible to link local public lib in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a public lib written in flutter, when I develop the app in local machine. I just want to modify the public lib and make it take effect immediately. In the production environment, I want the app using the published lib. is it possible to archive this in flutter. when switch with develop and production environment, I do not want to change the `pubspec.yaml` every time, it seems like the `npm link`. does flutter do like this possible?

the workflow I am doing is:

- modify the public lib
- publish to public repo
- change the app version and update the app to make it using the new lib

what I want:

- modify the public lib
- using the public lib modified code in current app
- debugging passed, publish the public lib, publish the local app and no need to modify the local app `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can specify the path to the local package directory in your app's pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  my_package:
    path: /path/to/my_package
```

for further information, you could check this [how to use local flutter package in another flutter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238420/how-to-use-local-flutter-package-in-another-flutter-application)